# JQuery get selected/single value of data with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i get each value of data-id. I need when `<a>` selected, it just pass a single value. I hope you can get what i mean. Thanks

```
<tr>
    <td>Satu</td>
    <td>
        <a class="bedit" data-id="11">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dua</td>
    <td>
        <a class="bedit" data-id="12">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>tiga</td>
    <td>
        <a class="bedit" data-id="13">edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('a.bedit').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Add to array like this

```
var dataID = [];
$('a.bedit').each(function () {
    dataID.push($(this).data('id')); //adds into array
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple javascript code to get the data-id.
Put this function in window onload or body - onload :-

```
function load() {
    var elemDom= document.getElementsByClassName('bedit');

    for(var count=0; count < elemDom.length; count++)
    {
        elemDom[count].onclick = function() {
            alert(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
        };
    }
}
```